# How do you make a duplicate of an object a separate object?

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

I'm currently working on a tutorial of a pencil, and I created a duplicate of the shaft of the pencil I created so I could start a new one that has a similar diameter to the first one. However, it is still the same object, and I want to make it separate from the original. What do I do?

Comment: You would have to duplicate the object without checking "linked" data.  If you wish to unlink the objects afterwards, you can go to object-relations-unlink, and choose which attributes you want to unlink.

Comment: Where is Object Relations? I want to find that to unlink the objects, but I don't know where that is.

Comment: Go to Object first, and then in the drop down menu, choose relations.

Comment: If you just selected the shaft in edit mode and then did SHFT-D to duplicate it you can just press 'P' Seperate > selection. Then go back into object mode and your duplicated shaft will be a new object and will show as one in the outliner.

Answer (score 2):

If you have duplicated an object and checked linked when you wanted to model them separately you can unlink them.  Here is an example:

[image]

If you have duplicated the mesh in edit mode, then separate them by selecting the mesh you want to separate, right clicking and choosing separate.  Here is an example:

[image]